# do I need to call mysql_thread_init if I link against libmysqld?

Tags: c++, mysql, multithreading, embedded

I have a program that links against libmysqld. Under linux I am able to execute "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" under Windows the same command make the application to crash. I saw a bug report relating the crash to use of mysql_thread_init(), however calling mysql_thread_init() crash my application under Windows.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Read the docs for `mysql_thread_init()` (including the user comment): http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-thread-init.html  If you still have problems, post a minimal program (maybe have it only make an init() call) that crashes and show us how you built it. Explaining exactly what you mean by "crash" might help, too (for example, is there an error message?).

Comment: The overview docs on threaded clients might also be of value: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/threaded-clients.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to trace the problem using mingw.

My application executes under linux load data local infile '/home/cquiros/temp/test.csv'. Under Windows it executes load data local infile 'c:\temp\test.csv' . Because Windows uses \  \t is interpreted as tab . Passing a tab as part of the load data local infile makes libmysqld to crash if the application is built using nmake (Visual C++) no idea why. Using mingw-make libmysqld is able to report the message "File not found".

I replaced all \ to / and now all works fine.